# Save PDF to file fails for remote location in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: files, remote

If I am using Firefox in private mode and I choose to save a page as PDF to a file location on a network drive the print dialog appears, I set the filename and location, click Print, there is a popup saying it is printing, but the file never appears in the destination.  Following the same procedure works fine on the local drive.  Also, printing to a network printer works when the printer is online.This is new, it started about 2 months ago, but I wasn't verifying that files appeared until a month later when I saw that last month's file was missing.